# i want to dispaly the return value of a function in a HTML element but the returned value is NAN

Tags: javascript

I would like to output the returned value of a function in a HTML element but i always get NAN as output. where could i be going wrong.

i have tried displaying the output inside the function and this seems to work alright but when i try to return the value in a function and assign it to a variable every things goes wrong.

```html
Input number<input type="text" name="" id="number1"> 
Input number<input type="text" name="" id="number2">

<button onclick="results2()">divide</button>

<p id="demo">Results</p>

<script>
  var results2 = function divide() {
    numberOne = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    numberTwo = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    return (numberOne / numberTwo);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results2();
</script>
```

when i key in any values in the text fields under id number1 and number2 above say 2 and 1 i expect the value returned by the function to be 2 that i should output in inner HTML of the id demo. instead i get a NAN

Comment: Be sure to do something with the return value (set the `demo` element to the result of the division).

Comment: That code runs before you put anything in the inputs

Comment: @ggorlen division implicitly converts to numbers

Comment: You're right! Thanks--corrected.

Comment: `results2()` also doesn't update any part of the DOM when it's called (as far as I can tell)

Comment: @RSchneyer well, except when it's called in `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results2();`

Comment: @VLAZ good point, I should have said when it's called by the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're setting the `innerHTML` of the `demo` div before the user clicks the button. Just move that into your function so it doesn't get set until the button is clicked:

```html
Input number<input type="text" name="" id="number1"> 
Input number<input type="text" name="" id="number2">

<button onclick="divide()">divide</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function divide() {
    numberOne = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    numberTwo = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Result: ' + numberOne / numberTwo;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is closer to what you're trying to do:

```html
Input number<input type="text" name="" id="number1"> Input number<input type="text" name="" id="number2">

<button onclick="handler()">divide</button>

<p id="demo">Results</p>

<script>
  function divide() {
    var numberOne = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var numberTwo = document.getElementById("number2").value;
    return numberOne / numberTwo;
  }

  function handler() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = divide();
  }
</script>
```